Effect of condensation pressure drop in open flow
If saturated gas flows through a tube that is being cooled, the gas will start to condense, forming droplets at some point in the tube. Looking at the individual condensation "cells", I imagine them like small implosions with local pressure drops. How do these effect the flow dynamics on the macro scale?
Intuitively I guess they would further draw the flow downstream, due to the local pressure gradients. Does this not amount to a macro effect? For example, I have never seen talk about regarding the pressure drop in industrial tube-and-shell-condensers (e.g. for heat pumps).

Google “two phase flow”

@ChetMiller I know what two phase flow is and I have worked with their mathematical models (homogeneous vs heterogeneous etc) a bit. I also know that condensation in a closed system can lead to implosion. I am still missing some understanding on how this pressure drop affects open macro flow (which occurs, as I know, quasi-isobarically). Can you point me to a good resource that could answer this question?

Is gravity present so that the condensate can gravitationally segregate as the droplets grow?

Yes, but I dont understand how it would be a different scenario. The first condensation/implosion-cell(s) will have the same effect on the macro flow, whether there is gravity or not. Right?
